# Why complex gradient of $g(z) = \kappa + a^*z + z^*b + z^* C z$ is $\frac{\partial g(z) }{\partial z^*} = b + C z$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am trying to understand the complex gradient fundamentals here. 
For example in [1, Example A.3(3)]--also attached the snapshot below for the convenience
[image] .

How to arrive at the complex gradient of $g(z) = \kappa  + a^*z + z^*b + z^* C z \ ,$ where $a,b,z \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times 1}$, and $C \in M_{n,n} \left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ (not necessarily it is Hermitian matrix) as  $\frac{\partial g(z) }{\partial z^*} = b + C z$ ?

I think the rules of complex-valued gradients would/should be different from the real-valued gradients since $${\rm Tr}\left(X^* Y\right) \neq {\rm Tr}\left(Y^* X \right)$$ or $$x^* y \neq y^* x$$

My question is, should I treat the conjugate component as a "constant"?
In other words, if
\begin{align}
g(z) &=  \kappa  + a^*z + z^*b + z^* C z \\
     & = \kappa  + \overline{a} : z + \overline{z}:b + \overline{z} : C z \ ,
\end{align}
where $\overline{z}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $z$, and $x : y = {\rm Tr} \left( x^T y \right) = x^T y$.

So, if I want to compute the derivate of $g(z)$ w.r.t. $z^*$ and treat $z$ as a "constant" (if my hypothesis is correct), then the differential will read
\begin{align}
dg(z) 
& = \underbrace{\overline{a} : dz}_{0} + \underbrace{ d\overline{z}:b }_{= \ b \ : \ d\overline{z} } + \underbrace{d\overline{z} : C z}_{ = \ C z \ : \ d\overline{z}} + \underbrace{\overline{z} : C dz}_{0}\ \\
&= b \ : \ d\overline{z} +  C z \ : \ d\overline{z} \\
&= \left( b  +  C z \right) : \ d\overline{z} \ ,
\end{align}
then, the gradient is
$$\frac{\partial g(z) }{\partial z^*} = b + C z \ .$$

Am I on the correct path? Thank you for your patience.

**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozfvR.png)** *Sayed, Ali H.*, [**Adaptation, learning, and optimization over networks**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1561/2200000051), Found. Trends Mach. Learn. 7, No. 4-5, 311-801 (2014). [ZBL1315.68212](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1315.68212).

Comment: Are these the Wirtinger derivatives?

Comment: Correct, that's what I understand so far.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you are on the right path with this derivation.

Comment: @greg: thank you very much for the confirmation.